# \dimexpr replacement/"expansion" without eTeX

Tags: bookmarks, e-tex, dimension-expressions

I want to use `\'{\i}` in a bookmark. While it works without problems when eTeX is there, I cannot use e.g. `\dimexpr` without eTeX. (And the current version of my TeX distribution does not contain eTeX support yet.) Is it possible to "expand" the `\doaccenti` into a form which TeX understands without eTeX, please?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doaccenti}{\8\number\dimexpr0.00390625\dimexpr\number"00EDsp\relax\relax
\expandafter\HyPsd@unichar@second@byte\expandafter{%
\number\numexpr"00ED-256*\number\dimexpr0.00390625\dimexpr\number"00EDsp%
\relax\relax\relax}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section[\texorpdfstring{\'{\i}}{\ifpdfstringunicode{\doaccenti}{i}}]{\'{\i}}

Text.

\end{document}
```

---

Thank you for the answers!

> I'm curious now: which (La)TeX distribution are you using? (in which version and OS)

MacKichan ScientificWorkPlace 5.50 Build 2960 (Windows XP)

> But you'd better upgrade you TeX distribution if possible

It is the recent version. A new version is planned.

> \section[\texorpdfstring{\'{\i}}{%
>     \ifpdfstringunicode{\string\000\string\355}{i}}]{\'{\i}}
>   works with LaTeX built on "Knuth TeX".

Thus SWP is not LaTeX built on "Knuth TeX", unfortunately (does not compile).

I tried

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\def\doaccenti{\80\355}

\begin{document}

\section[\texorpdfstring{\'{\i}}{\ifpdfstringunicode{\doaccenti}{i}}]{\'{\i}}

Text.

\end{document}
```

(as well as the other approaches), but got a:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=5000].
@if ...1expandafter @gobbletwo string #2endcsname 
                                                  {let #1#2}
l.1449 \newif\ifcheckat@

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

:-( What can I do now?

(Sorry for posting as answer & thanks Mr Scharrer! I did not see any "Comment" fields because I was not registered yet. Changed that now.)

OK, I found that even

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section[\texorpdfstring{i}{i}]{i}
Text.
\end{document}
```

does not compile, but

**Solution**:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{white}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section[\texorpdfstring{\'{\i}}{\ifpdfstringunicode{\80\355}{i}}]{\'{\i}}

Text.

\end{document}
```

does function properly!

Nevertheless, while this solved the problem, I would still be curious why the

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{white}
```

is needed?!

Comment: I'm curious now: which (La)TeX distribution are you using? (in which version and OS)

Comment: why can't you simply use `\section{\'{\i}}` with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: In some older TeX distribution, `pdftex` didn't support e-TeX extensions and `pdfetex` existed to that purpose.

Comment: @Stephen: You created accidentally two different unregistered accounts. I merged them together so that you can edit your question again. I also moved your second post into the answer. Please consider registering your account to avoid these things. Thank you.

Comment: My best answer to "What can I do now" is: leave SWP and use directly LaTeX. You'll lose a (questionable) wysiwyg interface while getting the last versions of the TeX software without waiting for MacKichan to keep the pace.

Comment: @egreg: But I would lose MuPaD (I don't need that interface).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `\numexpr` and `\dimexpr` do nothing but origin TeX can do. But you'd better upgrade you TeX distribution if possible.

Anyway:

```
% \number\dimexpr0.00390625\dimexpr\number"00EDsp\relax\relax
\@tempdima="00EDsp
\@tempdimb=0.00390625\@tempdima
\@tempcntb=\@tempdimb
\number\@tempcntb
```

and

```
% \number\numexpr"00ED-256*\number\dimexpr0.00390625\dimexpr\number"00EDsp\relax\relax\relax
\@tempdima="00EDsp
\@tempdimb=0.00390625\@tempdima
\@tempcntb=\@tempdimb
\@tempcnta="00ED
\multiply\@tempcntb by 256
\advance\@tempcnta by \@tempcntb
\number\@tempcnta
```

However, the result of `\doaccenti` is a constant. You can simply use

```
\def\doaccenti{\80\355}
```

to express unicode character í.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted answer, although \usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{white} is additionally needed, but that seems to be specific to SWP. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to write the correct octal strings in the bookmark file, the code

```
\section[\texorpdfstring{\'{\i}}{%
  \ifpdfstringunicode{\string\000\string\355}{i}}]{\'{\i}}
```

works with LaTeX built on "Knuth TeX".