# What's the difference between pdfTeX and pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex

I've been working on a project and compiled it using pdfLaTeX, then tried to compile using pdftex and got a whole lot of errors. I'd like to know why that would happen since it's a very plain file and I did not put a `pdflatex` option in `documentclass` or anything like that, and what's the real difference between them.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you have on your system? It's a bit puzzling, to say the least, that a file you describe as being "very plain" (i.e., plain TeX, right?) would compile when run under `pdflatex` but won't compile at all under `pdftex`.

Comment: @Mico: I use Tex Live

Comment: @Mico: I meant plain as in not fancy, but I suppose it doesn't use any of the extra macros provided by Latex over plain Tex.

Comment: "A whole lot of errors" - you expect us to guess them. Sorry, but my crystal ball is out for repair. Please read [how to ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and [how to report bugs](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html). You will also find [some background about TeX](http://www.tug.org/levels.html) helpful.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If a .tex file starts with `\documentclass` -- or, possibly, the now-obsolete `\documentstyle` command -- it's a file that needs to be compiled by a TeX engine that loads the `LaTeX` *format file* rather than the `Plain TeX` format file. Format files (or, shorter, "formats") are, loosely speaking, large collections of macros. There are many TeX formats; nowadays, the best known formats -- other than the original PlainTeX format -- are LaTeX (LaTeX2e, to be a bit more precise) and ConTeXt.

The LaTeX(2e) format is, to a first approximation, a large superset of the Plain-TeX format. It's not a *strict* superset, though, because there are some "Plain TeX" macros that aren't implemented in LaTeX. Hence, `.tex` files that contain LaTeX commands cannot be compiled if the PlainTeX format is loaded instead of the LaTeX format.

Note that the `\documentclass` instruction is itself a "LaTeX"-specific macro, i.e., it is not recognized by "Plain TeX". Therefore, `pdftex` (which loads the "plain TeX" format) cannot proceed properly once it encounters the `\documentclass` instruction on line 1 of the input file.

**Addendum**: For more information on TeX formats see, for instance, the webpage [TeX formats and engines](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/TeXvariants-and-engines.xhtml) as well as the TeX.SE page [List of TeX formats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38895/list-of-tex-formats).

Comment: Are `{pdf,lua,xe}latex` really formats? I thought LaTeX and ConTeXt were the only widely used *formats* nowadays, while XeTeX et. al. are different *compilers*.

Comment: @You: I thought ConTeXt was an editor.  And I believe what Mico means by *format* is *language* or *dialect* (in the computer languages sense).

Comment: @You: see the addendum to my answer for more information on TeX formats.

Answer (score 29):

`pdftex` expects the file to be plain TeX.  `pdflatex` expects it to be LaTeX.  These are two different dialects of TeX.  You do not expect a C compiler to work with Java, do you?

Note that in practice `pdftex` and `pdflatex` are often the same command, which analyzes how it was called to switch to the proper input language.  On some systems `gcc` behaves in the same way, compiling C if it is called as `gcc` or Fortran if it is called as `gfortran`.

Comment: The latter part is the reason why I asked this question. It seemed like the two engines were used/mentioned everywhere interchangeably as if they were the exact same.

Comment: Well, many plain TeX commands are available in LaTeX, and some packages (pstricks, pgf/tikz, babel and many others) are written to work in plain, LaTeX and even in ConTeXt. So these dialects are close - but not identical.

Comment: @AymanElmasry: `pdflatex` is _not_ an engine. See [this link](http://www.tug.org/levels.html) for more information.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Your link: "Engines: TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, … These are the actual executable binaries which implement the different TeX dialects. The LaTeX format is implemented with both **the pdfTeX (pdflatex)** and XeTeX (xelatex) **engines**, for example. When someone says “TeX can't find my fonts”, they usually mean an engine."

Comment: @MartinSchröder: "pdflatex is not an engine". What is it then?

Comment: @Tim: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63994/5763

Comment: Perhaps a better analogue would be C and C++. You can compile most C programs with a C++ compiler, but not the other way around.

Comment: So, is it the case that XeTeX and LuaTeX expect plain TeX scripting to process, while XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX expect LaTeX scripting to process?  And, when I frequently read about folks using LuaTeX and XeTeX (and PdfTeX) they are, more accurately, using Xe*, Lua* of PdfLaTeX?

Comment: Absolutely right.