# Is pdflatex an engine or a format?

Tags: pdftex, format-files

From http://www.tug.org/levels.html

> Engines: TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, … These are the actual executable
>   binaries which implement the different TeX dialects. The LaTeX format
>   is implemented with both the pdfTeX (**pdflatex**) and XeTeX (xelatex)
>   engines, for example. When someone says “TeX can't find my fonts”,
>   they usually mean an engine.
>
> Formats: LaTeX, plain TeX, **pdfLaTeX**, … These are the TeX-based
>   languages in which you actually write documents. When someone says
>   “TeX is giving me this mysterious error”, they usually mean a format.
>
> At a high level, the output format that gets used depends on the
>   program you invoke. If you run latex (which implements the LaTeX
>   format), you will get DVI; if you run **pdflatex** (which also
>   implements the LaTeX format), you will get PDF.

Is pdflatex an engine or a format?

What is the relation between pdflatex and pdftex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In comments I listed all the "latex" formats that got installed by default in my texlive 2012 installation.

```
texmf-var/web2c/eptex/platex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/euptex/uplatex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/luatex/dvilualatex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/luatex/lualatex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/cslatex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/mllatex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfcslatex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt 
texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt
```

One has to be careful though as they are not all "latex" in the sense of being a compiled version of an unmodified latex set of macros.

I believe `latex.fmt` and `pdflatex.fmt` only differ in that the same `latex.ltx` file was dumped with tex and pdftex respectively. (Actually `latex.fmt` is these days dumped with pdftex in dvi etex mode rather than classic tex) But for example `cslatex` is a different format, made by compiling the tex macros in

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/cslatex.ini
```

This file makes some small number of definitions setting a non standard encoding regime if I recall correctly, and then inputs the standard latex. This is all above board and as expected, you can do just about anything you want with the latex sources except call a changed copy latex (and if you read the small print you can even do that if you claim you must) `pdfcslatex.fmt` is of course the same source as this, but dumped with pdftex.
I'd need to check but I think the xelatex and lulatex formats similarly make some small (or not so small) additions to the standard latex macros as well as being dumped by the xetex and luatex engines respectively.

Comment: With TeXLive 2012 (and may be 2011, 2010, 2009...), both `latex.fmt` and `pdflatex.fmt` are produced by `pdfTeX` engine.

Comment: yes thanks you missed an edit that went in a minute or two before your comment:-)

Comment: In fact, the path of each format file contains the name of the *TeX engine used to produce it.

Comment: @PolGab so it does:-), I'm going to bed, why don't you write an answer, you seem to have a better grasp of current setup:-)

Comment: Thanks! (1) Does "some macros being dumped by some engine" mean the macros being pre-compiled by the engine? (2) "In comments I listed all the "latex" formats that got installed by default in my texlive 2012 installation." "LaTex" is a format itself, so are "PlainTeX" and "ConTeXt". So what does "'latex' formats" mean?

Comment: (2) I meant literally the list you get if you do ls \*latex\*.fmt (or dir instead of ls on windows) That is all formats with "latex" in their name. My point was that there is a difference (in respect of the latex licence if nothing else) between *latex fomats like pdflatex which are unchanged sources compiled with a different engine (so _are_ latex as far as the latex licence conditions go) and cslatex which are modified sources so are a derived work allowed under the latex licence (1) yes (I if I understand the question) dump is technically more correct than compile as it is invoked by \dump

Comment: Is cslatex a macro package as LaTex, or a compiled binary as pdfLaTex?

Comment: as I said that was a list of fmt files ie binary \dump outpurt, but the source is the same as that of latex except for a few macros changing the font and input encoding setuup

Answer (score 12):

`pdflatex` is a terminal command that tells the `pdfTeX` engine to use the `LaTeX` format.

**Correction**

Strictly speaking, `pdflatex` loads the `pdfLaTeX` format, but as far as the user is concerned this is identical to the `LaTeX` format. The additional commands that are available when using `pdflatex` (mostly starting with `\pdf`) are provided by the `pdfTeX` engine, not the format.

Comment: Do you think something is wrong with the second appearance of pdflatex?

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that I forgot to capitalise the 't' and 'x'? One has to answer quickly around these parts!

Comment: @Tim if you mean in the part you quote, no.  The sentence reads "The LaTeX format is implemented with both the pdftex and xetex engines" The parts in the parentheses are simply clarifying which formats are implemented with which engines.  (Of course the sentence should also include the luaTeX engine in the list, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: @Tim not really latex and pdflatex are the same format in the sense that they are a compilation of the same tex source, but technically a format file is a memory dump made by the engine that is going to use it so in my texlive I have separate pdflatex.fmt and latex.fmt files:

Comment: /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/eptex/platex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/euptex/uplatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/dvilualatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/luatex/lualatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/cslatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/mllatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfcslatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt

Comment: IanThompson and @Alan: I mean the pdflatex in my second quote. so I think your comments misunderstood me.

Comment: @Tim Then again, no. The pdfLaTeX format includes some different functionality from the LaTeX format (even though they both use the pdfTeX engine.) So they're not identical.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- Clearly this is more complicated than I thought. Could you post an answer? I'm quite interested in the details now.

Comment: @AlanMunn --- My previous comment applies to you as well, but I can only notify one user at a time.

Comment: @AlanMunn unlike (say) lualatex or cslatex I think pdflatex is made from an unchanged latex source isn't it (it used to be) so it onlt has extra primitives because pdftex has extra primitives over tex \pdf....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that's true. But from a user's point of view, pdflatex has different functionality from latex (e.g. postscript specials vs. pdf specials; different graphics inclusion etc.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- Is `latex.fmt` used by `pdfTeX` when running in `dvi` mode, or is it meant for use by the original `TeX` engine?

Comment: @IanThompson Ive put some stuff in an answer (but its 20 years since I really made formats (as opposed to just picking up tex live and it's 1 in the morning so it may not be coherent:-) pdftex doesn't switch formats when you switch modes the format is loaded the document starts to process and you can switch any time before the first page is shipped out as far as I recall. It may even be that web2c pdftex _can_ read classic tex formats (I'd have to check) but in principle you shouldn't expect that, a format is closely tied to the engine.

Comment: @AlanMunn: `pdflatex` with `-output-format dvi` option is equivalent to `latex`. And `latex` with `-output-format pdf` option is equivalent to `pdflatex`.  With modern distributions, both use pdfTeX engine.

Comment: @IanThompson  most these days are based on web2c so formats are portable across machines but that didn't use to be the case a unix tex.fmt couldn't be read by MSDOS emtex tex.fmt (even though both were classic tex)

Comment: @PolGab I think that's what I said: the engine is the same. The question is, is it fair to say that the latex format and the pdflatex format are different?

Comment: @AlanMunn: the only difference between latex.fmt and pdflatex.fmt is the default output format...

Comment: Oh, so `pdflatex` and `pdfLaTeX` are two different things?