# Loading latex from tex

Tags: pdftex, programming

I decided venture into the very basics of the world of TeX and LaTeX. I have been playing around with `tex`, `pdftex` and `latex` and after paying close attention to the binaries and not being able to figure out what is going on I decided it was time to come and ask for help from someone with knowledge.

### `latex` == `pdftex`

Are the `latex` and `pdftex` binaries the same? I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5 and this is what I have from the terminal:

```
jmlopez$ which pdftex
/usr/texbin/pdftex
jmlopez$ ls -al /usr/texbin/pdftex
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1662700 Jun 21  2011 /usr/texbin/pdftex
```

This tells me that pdftex is an actual binary which I can execute. Let us take a look at `latex`:

```
jmlopez$ which latex
/usr/texbin/latex
jmlopez$ ls -al /usr/texbin/latex
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  6 Feb 13  2012 /usr/texbin/latex -> pdftex
```

It seems that `latex` is a symbolic link to `pdftex`. So in reality, `latex` and `pdftex` and even `pdflatex` are the same program, that is `pdftex`.

### `pdftex`

The next set of commands displays what happens when I submit commands to pdftex:

```
jmlopez$ pdftex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode

*\show\newcommand
> \newcommand=undefined.
<*> \show\newcommand

?
```

`pdftex` is not `latex` since it doesn't know the definition of `\newcommand`. But now let us see what happens with `latex`.

### `latex`

```
jmlopez$ latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
 icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
 lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, slovak, sloven
ian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded
.

*\show\newcommand
> \newcommand=macro:
->\@star@or@long \new@command .
<*> \show\newcommand

?
```

From the first line when you enter `latex` and `pdftex` you can see that it is the exact same program. The only difference is that `pdftex` somehow knows that when it is executed as the symbolic link `latex` then it needs to load all the `latex` definition. Definitions which include the `\newcommand` macro.

### Loading `latex` from `pdftex` or `tex`

My actual question is, given that I have executed `pdftex` or `tex`, how can load `latex` so that all the macros that `latex` defines are available in `pdftex`?

The reason I wish to know this is because I want to find the actual files that defines all of these macros so that I can try to have a better understanding of what is going on when I use the command `latex`. I wish to know how `latex` defines all of its enviroments and how it knows where to look for its packages. Those may be other question for the future, but for now I just want to know if it is possible to load the `latex` macros from `pdftex` or `tex`.

Comment: Try `pdflatex` in the terminal.  The `pdfTeX` engine is used when you issue either the command `latex` or `pdflatex`; the `XeTeX` engine is used when you issue the command `xelatex`; and the `LuaTeX` engine is used when you issue the command `lualatex`.  All of these commands expect a LaTeX file.  There are other formats also, which don't want you to use commands that end `*latex` (e.g., 'plain' TeX or ConTeXt).  Probably a duplicate, however; see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36/8528).

Comment: @jon, I did try `pdflatex` in terminal. For this reason in my post I said: "So in reality, `latex` and `pdftex` and even `pdflatex` are the same program, that is `pdftex`". They all point to `pdftex`. I'm not ready to venture into `xelatex` or `LuaTeX`. For now all I wish to know is how `pdftex` knows when and how to load the `latex` macros.

Comment: Sorry: I missed the mention of `pdflatex`.  But this seems like a long way around to ask how `pdfTeX`-the-engine knows that you are asking for LaTeX when you type `(pdf)latex` in a terminal.  Compare `pdftex -fmt latex <filename>`, for example.

Comment: @jon, I read the other posts which talk about the differences between the different *tex versions but I don't see anything that explains how to get the core driver (in this case `pdftex`) to load all of the other `latex` macros.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91050/2417) contains the information you need. Best of luck trying to understand the `LaTeX` kernel code!

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer, but you can do this by using `latex` or `pdflatex`; why do you need to call `pdftex` *and* get 'all the other `latex` macros'?  (And what are all these other macros?  Many of important LaTeX things are in separate packages.)

Comment: @IanThompson -- As I said: *I'm* certainly not qualified to answer!!

Comment: @jon --- I'm not qualified either! I just happened to remember that someone who is qualified had effectively answered this elsewhere (though this question is not a duplicate of the one I'm linking to).

Comment: Yeah, not a duplicate I guess.  I don't know how to unflag it though....

Comment: @IanThompson, the link you provided is certainly helpful. I will study a little more going this route. In the meanwhile I hope this question is indeed **not** a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps also of interest is [miniltx.tex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/miniltx)

Comment: @jon --- I'm not sure what the protocol for this situation is. The relevant information clearly exists elsewhere on the site, but in an answer to a question that is quite different. Maybe I should ask about it on the meta site, but it's tea time and I'm hungry!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way the binaries are set up in texlive (at least) the binary uses its *name* to customise its behaviour. so `pdftex` and `pdflatex` might be copies (or symbolic links) of the same binary but one will load the plain TeX format and the other will load the `latex` format so their behaviour is very different.  The source for the latex format is `latex.ltx` or in its documented forms `source2e` try `texdoc source2e` or `kpsewhich latex.ltx` on the command line.

for further details see

[Executables of formats, engines and executables of engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64000/executables-of-formats-engines-and-executables-of-engines/64002#64002)

Comment: Speak of the devil...

Comment: So does that mean `pdftex -fmt latex <file>` does the same as `latex <file>`?

Comment: I had thought about the possibility that the pdftex binary uses its name for custom behavior but I wanted someone to verify it. The last two commands provided are big help. Is there a way to know the exact custom behavior for pdftex? What jon pointed out is interesting, the -ftm latex option seems to load all the necessary things from latex.

Comment: @jmlopez there is a question on site where it's detailed but the classic way is to have `virtex` with just the the primitives and then `latex` would be a script `virtex &latex` which loads latex format and `tex` would be `virtex &plain` to load plain tex (try `kpsewhich plain.tex`) but wev2c added the convenience of using the executable name to determine the format loaded if you make your own `mytexfmt` format then you can make a symbolic link `mytexfmt` to the tex executable to get an executable that preloads your format.

Comment: added link to answer