# Is it wrong to call XeLaTeX an "engine"?

Tags: xetex, format-files, engine

We know the engines to the TeX family are binary executables that compile TeX files. People sometimes mention `XeLaTeX` as being an *engine*; so here's the question: Is it wrong to call `XeLaTeX` an engine? If it's not, then what to call it?

Comment: XeTeX is the engine, XeLaTeX is a format built for that engine.

Comment: @Skillmon Is it wrong to call XeLaTeX, the _format_, as an _engine_ or a _compiler_? or they are conceptually different?

Comment: A format in the TeX world is something like a byte-dump of an engines state at some point. The mis-concept that XeLaTeX is an engine or binary stems from the fact that `xelatex` in most TeX distributions is the call for something like `xetex -fmt="xelatex"`, so the `xelatex` binary is no binary but a link to the `xetex` binary with the XeLaTeX format preloaded.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499438/134574.

Comment: It should be noted that initex creates an executable by stopping the TeX engine after adding all the standard macros.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116709/if-latex-is-only-a-macro-package-why-does-it-have-its-own-executable/116711?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#116711

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly opinion-based answer, as I'm not sure if there actually is a general reference for all this terminology.

I usually use "...TeX" (spelled with alternating upper-/lowercase letters) when I mean the *language*, i.e. the collection of all predefined macros, assignments, specific primitives etc. which can be used in this specific TeX variant.

On the other hand, I use `...tex` (all lowercase letters, and often with monospace markup) when I mean a specific *compiler*, i.e. a compiled binary that implements a certain set of primitive commands and behavior, or when I mean a precompiled *format*, which is just a pre-compiled set of definitions used by a compiler.

The latter makes things a bit more complicated, as with modern TeX distributions the distinction between compiler and format isn't so clear anymore. For example, if you'd like to compile a XeLaTeX file, you'd run a command like `xelatex myfile.tex`. Here `xelatex` behaves like a compiler but (as far as I know) actually is just a wrapper binary around the call of the `xetex` compiler which preloads the `xelatex` format which in turn defines all the macros used by the XeLaTeX language.

Because of this distinction, I tend to avoid the term "engine". One could call only compilers an engine, because only they provide the core functionality that is necessary to compile files of a certain language. But one could also use the term for compilers and formats, because for all the common format variants they are basically the same from a user's perspective. At least I would never use the term "engine" for the language.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your words, finally I don't know, is it right to call <XeLaTeX> as an engine or not? or what should we call it in general? This guy Ian Thompson, in this link "https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63995/71461" says `pdflatex` (like the `xelatex`) is a terminal command (as you mentioned) -- But just a terminal command not anything else! I'm confused now, what is truly right and straight to call `xelatex` in default, since it can be considered as a compiler from a user's perspective?

Comment: I must admit that the concepts in the TeX world are not that clearly separated as for most other programming languages. For example, the distinction between C, the language, and `gcc`, the compiler, is much clearer than between XeLaTeX and `xelatex`. In theory we could have several different implementations for the XeLaTeX language with different names. So to me there's still a difference between the language per se and the loaded format file, while both can be referred to as "XeLaTeX". I try to make the distinction clearer by using a different spelling/markup.

Comment: `xelatex` is not a wrapper around `xetex` but a symbolic link to `xetex` so they are actually the same file.  On startup, the executable checks the name it was called with and if the name ends with `latex`, the LaTeX format is preloaded.