# Should TexLive map pdflatex to pdftex?

Tags: pdftex, installing, texlive, mactex

On my computer (OS X 10.7.5; last versions of MacTeX and TeXShop)

`/usr/texbin` is an alias for `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/`

and in there

`pdflatex` is an alias for `pdftex`

Is this a bug or a feature?

Trying to compile the code below, seems to suggest I might also have a problem with `biber`, as well. How do I need to proceed to clean up my installation, in a way that reinstalling both MacTeX and TeXShop will give me something functional?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{game.bib}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
            Here is text \footfullcite{vNM1944theory}.
            Here is text \fullcite{vNM1944theory}.
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Thanks for reading.

```
    @book{vNM1944theory,
      title={The theory of games and economic behavior},
      author={Von Neumann, John and Morgenstern, Oskar},
      year={1944},
      publisher={Princeton university press}
    }
```

[image: output]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `data source /var/folders/8j/bx2qhrfj7vxd5n7y22409zj40000gn/T/par-636564726963/cache-955b5cd96386991ca6623279060097e4c757d28e/inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .`

Comment: Try to remove the cache folder and start biber again.

Comment: Do you mean .aux files or something else?

Comment: This folder: `/var/folders/8j/bx2qhrfj7vxd5n7y22409zj40000gn/T/par-636564726963/cache-955b5cd9‌​6386991ca6623279060097e4c757d28e/`

Comment: Regarding the 'bug' vs 'feature' question, [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63994/8528) might prove enlightening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature! The same binary is used for the functionality, and which one is selected depends on the name you use to start it.

Comment: It's worth noting that `pdftex` *very likely* looks at `argv[0]` to see what it was called as, selecting the default format from there.  That's how it can tell.

Comment: Yes it does IIRC.