# pdflatex commandline hide compilation output

Tags: terminal-output

My program produces multiple outputs: I have a .tex file compiled, and some of them are produced in the command-line. The compilation info of pdf-latex is useless to me and I would like to hide it to make my command-line output readable.

I have seen [this](http://tug.org/pipermail/texworks/2009q4/001984.html) site mention some box-thicking should do it, but I haven't found a command-line equivalent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can either redirect all of the `pdflatex` output:

- for sh: `pdflatex ... > /dev/null 2>&1`
- for cmd: `pdflatex ... > NUL 2>&1`

Or you can use the `-quiet` option:

```
pdflatex -quiet ...
```

Comment: the quiet-option would be perfect, but

"pdflatex: unrecognized option '-quiet'"

Comment: @Haxelaar Hmm, it seems to be present for the MiKTeX 2.9 `pdflatex` version, but the Arch Linux TeXLive version does not have it indeed. Then redirecting output is your only option. You can leave out the `2>&1` bit if you still want to show errors (and maybe warnings, depending on how `pdflatex` outputs them).

Comment: Using `pdflatex --interaction=batchmode ...` hides almost all of the output

Answer (score 16):

In my case, there is no `-quiet` mode. So I had to use `-interaction=batchmode` argument as suggeseted by [Andrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30471/andrew)'s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166658/pdflatex-commandline-hide-compilation-output#comment877528_166659).

But then another problem arised - you will not see what went wrong and why, because **errors are also suppressed with `batchmode`**.

The result I end up using is to suppress all `pdflatex`'s output by using `grep` to output only errors:

```bash
: | pdflatex -halt-on-error src.tex | grep '^!.*' -A200 --color=always
```

I use `-halt-on-error` because you basically can't use interactive mode in case of error (`grep` disables dialog between program and user). Also, to make sure that `pdflatex` does never prompt for the input, let's pipe in command with no output (`:` command).

Let me also explain the `grep` arguments:

- `^!.*`

  - string to search for in the output from pdflatex
  - it matches all lines that start with `!`, which are considered error lines
- `-A200`

  - output 200 lines after every match
  - this way I make sure to **print also the relevant information followed after the matched error lines**
- `--color=always`

  - this provides us colored output so that we can clearly see what went wrong and why - **the problem is bold red**

---

### Wrapper script

I've created a wrapper script to provide more convenient solution exactly for this purpose. It's usage is almost the same as `pdflatex` / `pdftex` itself. You can check it out as [a CTAN package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdftex-quiet) or as [a GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/jirislav/pdftex-quiet).

#### Quickinstall

And here is how to install the latest version using this oneliner:

```bash
curl -s https://gitlab.com/jirislav/pdftex-quiet/raw/latest/pdftex-quiet | \
    sudo tee /usr/local/bin/pdftex-quiet >/dev/null \
    && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/pdftex-quiet \
    && sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/pdftex-quiet /usr/local/bin/pdflatex-quiet
```

Here is an example of how you run the wrapper script:

```bash
pdftex-quiet compile-me.tex
# You may also provide additional attributes to `pdflatex`
pdflatex-quiet -output-format=dvi -output-directory=/tmp compile-me.tex
```

You can also show version or help of the `pdflatex-quiet` / `pdftex-quiet` script:

```bash
pdflatex-quiet -v  # or --version
pdflatex-quiet -h  # or --help
```

Also the difference between `pdflatex-quiet` and `pdftex-quiet`, [as explained here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41048/134632) is respected - thanks to Denis Bitouzé's comment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very nice contribution!

Comment: Thank you :) I've further improved the proposed answer so that it has disabled `stdin` when running `pdflatex` with `:` command, because it would seem to hang up when it prompts for input (grep doesn't print characters until newline is printed, so you can't possibly know what it's waiting for). Oh and I've found out that `pdflatex` always prints `!` at the start of the line describing problem, so I've also updated the `grep` expression and added colored output so that you see exactly what have failed. And finally, I've added final `pdf/div` filename to be printed in the bash script on success.

Comment: Would you like to submit it to CTAN?

Comment: I've never submitted anything there until now :) .. I've called it `pdfla­tex-quiet`

Comment: perhaps you could get in touch with Latexmk maintainer and suggest incorporation into it

Comment: I tested it but had an issue (`pdflatex-quiet test` leads to `! Undefined control sequence. \documentclass` as if underlying `pdftex` instead `pdflatex` has been used). The problem is, issues should be reported on [your private GitLab instance](https://gitlab.jkozlovsky.cz/) and it is impossible to register on it.

Comment: @jirislav Very nice work. May I politely suggest you contact the maintainer of `latexmk` john collins who frequently hangs around here and try to has out a `perl` equivalent of this `shell` script. I can visualise how useful a `latexmk` integration of this might be, especially to those who are using `latexmk` as the build system.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé oh, I didn't know you have to be registered in order to file an issue - that's why I've just moved the project to the public GitLab.com domain, so that you can [file the issue there](https://gitlab.com/jirislav/pdftex-quiet/issues/new), thank you.

Comment: @Krishna and [@jfbu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4686/jfbu), thank you for suggesting to get in touch with Latexmk maintainer, I'm gonna put it on my todo list

Comment: @DenisBitouzé ok, now I've understood what the problem was - I didn't notice the difference between pdfTeX and pdfLaTeX, but now I do, so I'm about to release new fixed version which works for both pdfTeX & pdfLaTeX very soon, thank you for reporting this

Comment: @johncollins would you be able to pull in this functionality into `latexmk`? I think this is a wonderful addition

Comment: @jirislav Would this work for the `lualatex` and `xelatex` executables also (and not merely `pdftex`?

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, https://ctan.org/pkg/texfot was my attempt at solving this problem -- eliminating the verbose output from tex engines while still showing the interesting messages (the ones I actually want to do something about). --karl

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 5):

### Update 2023-02-05

I have switched to [tectonic](https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/en-US/) and no longer use the solution below.

### tex-to-pdf compiler bash function

I ended up combining the answers from
[rubenvb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/174/rubenvb),
[Andrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30471/andrew) and
[jirislav](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134632/jirislav)
and putting it as a function in my `.bashrc`.

### Short version

All the output is redirected in a `.txt` file.
The error messages of this file are displayed and the `.txt` file removed.

You can put the following function in your `.bashrc`:

```sh
function tex-pdf {
        pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode $1 > $1.txt
        grep '^!.*' --color=always $1.txt
        rm $1.txt
}
export -f tex-pdf
```

You can use it like

```
$ tex-pdf report
```

### Long version

If you use BibTeX or want to remove files that are created during compilation,
but you don't need, you can extend the function in the following way:

```sh
function tex-pdf {
    printf "Step 1/4 - pdflatex\n"
    pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode $1.tex > $1.txt
    grep '^!.*' --color=never $1.txt

    printf "Step 2/4 - bibtex\n"
    bibtex $1.aux > $1.txt
    grep '^!.*' --color=never $1.txt

    printf "Step 3/4 - pdflatex\n"
    pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode $1.tex > $1.txt
    grep '^!.*' --color=never $1.txt

    printf "Step 4/4 - pdflatex\n"
    pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode $1.tex > $1.txt
    grep '^!.*' --color=never $1.txt

    rm -f $1.txt $1.aux $1.bbl $1.blg $1.log $1.out $1.toc
}
export -f tex-pdf
```

If there are no errors in your code, the output will be:

```
$ tex-pdf report
Step 1/4 - pdflatex
Step 2/4 - bibtex
Step 3/4 - pdflatex
Step 4/4 - pdflatex
```