# TeXStudio: Create a command that opens a PDF file with a name based on that of the main tex file

Tags: texstudio, sumatrapdf

If I have a PDF file whose name is `<\jobname>~[solved].pdf` (with spaces in the absolute path and the file name), how can I create a TeXStudio user command that opens this file knowing that the following doesn't work in recognizing the intended full name:

> "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance
>   -inverse-search "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/texstudio/texstudio.exe\" \"%%f\" -line %%l" "?am [solved].pdf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution after some experimentation.

If the output PDF file is prefixed by a word `[solved]` and space (i.e. `[solved]~<\jobname>.pdf`), the command should be

> "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance
> -inverse-search ""C:/Program Files (x86)/texstudio/texstudio.exe" "%%f" -line %%l" ?a"[solved]" ?m.pdf

On the other hand, if it is appended by a space and a word `[solved]` (i.e. `<\jobname>~[solved].pdf`), the command should be

> "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance
> -inverse-search ""C:/Program Files (x86)/texstudio/texstudio.exe" "%%f" -line %%l" "?am ?"[solved]".pdf"

The key note here is to understand that a `space` is a terminating character, which needs to have a following `?` in order to use further selectors/pathname parts/terminating characters.

---

For TeXstudio v3.0, unknowingly, the syntax of the first case has to be slightly modified to be

> "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance
> -inverse-search ""C:/Program Files (x86)/texstudio/texstudio.exe" "%%f" -line %%l" ?a"[solved]" "?m".pdf

[image]

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search ""C:/Program Files (x86)/texstudio/texstudio.exe" "%%f" -line %%l" ?a [Exam]" ?m.pdf"`

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search ""C:/Program Files (x86)/texstudio/texstudio.exe" "%%f" -line %%l" ?a [Exam]" "?m".pdf`

Comment: `)` is a terminating character for the selector `?`. So, it should be `"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "?a)[Exam] ?m.pdf"`

Comment: `texfot  −−quiet lualatex -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "\AtBeginDocument{\printanswersfalse}\input{%}"` then call another user command to rename `cmd.exe /C ren "?am.pdf" "[Exam] ?m.pdf"`. Check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459694/2288)  for texfot and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37132708/2849383) for calling the command prompt.

Comment: All the info in [this file](https://pastebin.com/Z0PVbxiE).