# Document class problem?

Tags: errors

My text in thesis is as below:

```
%\documentclass[croppedpdf,pagebackref,showinstructions,showtodo]{adsphd}
%\documentclass[pagebackref,showinstructions,showtodo,showtodopriv,showlabels,biblatex,biber,biblatexstyle=authoryear]{adsphd}
%\documentclass[online]{adsphd}
%\documentclass[print]{adsphd}
\documentclass[pagebackref,showinstructions,showtodo,showtodopriv,showlabels,final,coverfontpercent=100]{adsphd}
```

When I compile, there is notification of documentclass problem, as shown below:

Command Line:

```
pdftex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "thesis.tex"
```

Startup Folder:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\solomonge\Desktop\thesis
```

Error Message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
("C:\Documents and Settings\solomonge\Desktop\thesis\thesis.tex"
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \documentclass
                  [pagebackref,showinstructions,showtodo,showtodopriv,showla...
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! It looks like you've run `pdftex` rather than `pdflatex`. Only the latter knows LaTeX commands like `\documentclass`. I'll see if I can find a question covering this: we certainly have some.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41031/whats-the-difference-between-pdftex-and-pdflatex