# Why are my exercise and answer references reading 10 (ten) too many?

Tags: formatting, programming

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\documentclass[english]{book}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{refcount} %
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} %
\usepackage{relsize} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop}
\usepackage{stackengine} %
\usepackage[skins,theorems,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{ifthen}\newboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
% --------------------------------------- START DECLARATIONS --------------------------------------------- %
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt; 1pt=0.3515mm

 \DeclareMathSizes{10}{10.2}{8.0}{7.2}
 \DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{11.20}{8.8}{8.0} % 10.95 11.20 8.8 8.0

\definecolor{ThemeColor}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.45} %
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{0.00,0.08,0.45} % #000086
\definecolor{DarkOrange}{rgb}{0.55,0.22,0.05} % #FB9902
\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.06,0.06} % #880000
\definecolor{LightGrey}{rgb}{0.96,0.96,0.96}
\definecolor{LightOrange}{rgb}{1.00,0.87,0.64} % #FB9902
\definecolor{LightYellow}{rgb}{1.00,1.00,0.85} %


\newcommand\Hrule{\noindent\color{ThemeColor}{\rule{\linewidth}{3pt}}} %

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\color{ThemeColor}\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont} %
{\Hrule\vspace*{6pt}\\ {\color{black}\,\chaptername\hspace{2pt}\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14} %
\selectfont{\thechapter}}} %
{0pt}{\bfseries\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont{#1}}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}[0pt] %
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}} % make-up of the numbering

\tcbset{myinnerbox/.style={no shadow,shrink tight,arc=1.0pt,extrude by=2mm,colframe=black,
  boxrule=0.7pt,frame style={opacity=0.25},interior style={opacity=0.5},colback=black!5!white}}
%
\renewcommand{\AtBeginExercise}{\vspace{0pt}} % before the first question
%
% to here
%
\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\newcounter{problem}[Exercise] %

\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercise}
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{\arabic{Question}\hspace{0.7pt}.\hspace{1.5pt}} %
\renewcommand{\subQuestionNB}{\alph{subQuestion}\hspace{0.7pt})\hspace{1.5pt}} %

% ------------------------------------------------ Spacings --------------------------------------------- %

\setlength{\QuestionBefore}{1pt} % before a new question was 2pt
\setlength{\subQuestionBefore}{-1pt} % space between two subquestions was -0.5pt
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{20pt} % indents whole
\setlength{\subQuestionIndent}{15.5pt} % indent of a) further was 16pt
\setlength{\Exesep}{0pt} % OK
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{18pt} % 16pt - for double-digits
%
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{firstanswerofthechapter}} %
{\newpage\noindent\hspace{1.5pt}\vspace*{8pt}
{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont{\text{Questions based on \hspace{1.2pt}}\text{\,CHAPTER \thechapter\,}}\;}\newline\newline % stop
\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}\stackunder[3.5pt]{\colorbox{LightOrange} %
{\fontsize{11.5}{14}\selectfont{\textcolor{ThemeColor}{Exercise~\ExerciseHeaderNB}}\smallskip}}
{\textcolor{DarkOrange}{\rule{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}}} % else
    {\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}\stackunder[3.5pt]{\colorbox{LightOrange} %
        {\fontsize{11.5}{14}\selectfont{\textcolor{ThemeColor}{Exercise~\ExerciseHeaderNB}}\smallskip}}
{\textcolor{DarkOrange}{\rule{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}}}}

\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{firstanswerofthechapter}} %
{\newpage\noindent\hspace{1.5pt}\vspace*{8pt}
{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont{\text{Answers to questions based on \hspace{1.2pt}}\text{\,CHAPTER \thechapter\,}}\;}\newline\newline % stop
\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}\stackunder[3.5pt]{\colorbox{LightOrange} % continue
{\fontsize{11.5}{14}\selectfont{\textcolor{ThemeColor}{Answers to exercise~\ExerciseHeaderNB\hspace{3.4pt}on \hspace{0.6pt}p\hspace{2.0pt}\pageref{\AnswerRef}}\,}\smallskip}}
{\textcolor{DarkOrange}{\rule{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}}} % else
    {\noindent\def\stackalignment{l}\stackunder[3.5pt]{\colorbox{LightOrange} %
        {\fontsize{11.5}{14}\selectfont{\textcolor{ThemeColor}{Answers to exercise~\ExerciseHeaderNB\hspace{3.4pt}on \hspace{0.6pt}p\hspace{2.0pt}\pageref{\AnswerRef}}\,}\smallskip}}
{\textcolor{DarkOrange}{\rule{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}}}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{} % Chapter 1
\label{chap:chapter_01}

\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{true}
\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_01_exer_01}] %
\Question{Question 1}
\Question{Question 2}
\end{Exercise}

\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_01_exer_02}]
\Question{Question 1}
\Question{Question 2}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_01_exer_03}]
\Question{Question 1}
\Question{Qustion 2}
\end{Exercise}

\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{true}
\begin{Answer}[ref={chap_01_exer_01}]
\Question{Answer to question 1}
\Question{Answer to question 2}
\end{Answer}

\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
\begin{Answer}[ref={chap_01_exer_02}]
\Question{Answer to question 1}
\Question{Answer to question 2}
\end{Answer}

\begin{Answer}[ref={chap_01_exer_03}]
\Question{Answer to question 1}
\Question{Answer to question 2}
\end{Answer}

\chapter{} % Chapter 2
\label{chap:chapter_02}

\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{true}
\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_02_exer_01}]
\Question{Question 1}
\Question{Question 2}
\end{Exercise}

\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_02_exer_02}]
\Question{Question 1 }
\Question{Question 2}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_02_exer_03}]
\Question{Question 1}
\Question{Question 2}
\end{Exercise}

\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{true}
\begin{Answer}[ref={chap_02_exer_01}]
\Question{Question 1}
\Question{Question 2}
\end{Answer}

\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false} 
\begin{Answer}[ref={chap_02_exer_02}]
\Question{Answer to question 1}
\Question{Answer to question 2}
\end{Answer}

\begin{Answer}[ref={chap_02_exer_03}]
\Question{Answer to question 1}
\Question{Answer to question 2}
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry it is a bug https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/38

Comment: there is a fix here (we can close as dup if you confirm this works for you) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427451/dot-between-chapter-number-and-figure-number-disapear-after-update

Comment: actually although it is the same issue the fix there is memoir specific I'll add an answer here

Comment: 2018-04-01 patch level 3 to fix this has been submitted to ctan so will be in the mirrors before long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry this is a bug in 2018-04-01 release it is fixed in patch level 3

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/38

For now you can do

```
\makeatletter
\def\counterwithin@x#1#2{%
  \@ifbothcounters{#1}{#2}%
      {\@addtoreset{#1}{#2}%
       \expandafter
       \gdef\csname the#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
            {\csname the#2\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
             .\expandafter% spot the dot :(
             \@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}}}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble.