# incorrect tables and figures numbering in memoir class

Tags: tables, floats, numbering, memoir

I have maybe a silly question. I am trying to write my class notes as a future book, I am using memoir class, but I have just noticed that my figures and tables are labeled like "figure 11" or "table 11" instead of the right way "table 1.1" or "figure 1.1". I am trying to use the recommendatios of previous post but I guess that maybe ¿is my mixtex 2.9 corrupted?
this is a sample tex that I am using. Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
%\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\begin{document}
    \mainmatter    %when using this the numbering changes
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
    \begin{figure}
    \caption{Caption 1}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Caption 2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you are using latex release 2018-04-01 patch level 2? sorry we broke it it is fixed in PL 3

Comment: I will check. I update regularly Miktex, I will try to update again and see, thanks

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428154/why-are-my-exercise-and-answer-references-reading-10-ten-too-many/428159#428159

Comment: apparently my Miktex version is updated. Where do you check the latex version?

Comment: thanks for the code at least is working, thank you so much!!

Comment: the top of the log file will say something like `LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2`  (or 3, which went to ctan only yesterday so may not be in miktex yet)