# Circumvent missing dot in hierarchical listing numbering

Tags: counters, latex-base

I'm trying to deal with the same problem as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427451/dot-between-chapter-number-and-figure-number-disapear-after-update). But the accepted answer does not really help in my case since the problem occurs when I try to add hierarchical numbering to listings and I need a solution that will still let me write

```
\counterwithin{listing}{chapter}
```

in my preamble. How can I achieve this? I cannot really wait for this to be patched or downgrade at the moment.

Comment: you don't have to wait it was fixed in the patch level 3 release and there have been two releases since then (current release is 2018-04-01 patch level 5)

Comment: This has already been fixed. Did you upgrade your latex installation.

Comment: I'm using pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (installed on Arch via pacman). Which version do I need?

Comment: We need to know exactly what you installed not which version of the binary, latex runs on top of the binary. Are there any latex related updates in arch? Generally I don't recommend getting latex from a Linux fist as they tend to quite behind on their updates, in this case there was an error in the initial release, an error that has already been fixed upstream. I have no idea when arch will pick up any updates. I generally use the upstream latex directly, tug.org/texlive

Comment: According to arch docs they should follow updates, but I don't know anything about how to do things in arch

Comment: when latex starts up it gives a banner on the terminal and log of the form `LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch release 5`   The bug that you refer to should not be there for releases from patch release 3 onwards

Comment: Ah yes, for me this is `patch level 2` so I will probably have to install the upstream version, thank you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If it's in `texlive-core`, it should be patched on Arch. I assume this would affect the binaries. `texlive-core` is `2018.47471-1` which I assume means committ 47471, though I'm not sure as I don't use distro-packaged TL.

Comment: @cfr it's not a binaries issue it is a single `.` missing from latex.ltx

Comment: installing a whole new tex distribution seems a heavyweight solution to a single missing `'`  in one macro.

Comment: @Peter What does `pacman -Qi texlive-core` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in a latex release that was only distributed for less than 2 weeks before a fix was posted. If you are still waiting for your tex distribution to get 2018-04-01 patch level 3 (and 4 and 5) then the fix is literally a one `.` change, just add this to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\def\counterwithin@x#1#2{%
  \@ifbothcounters{#1}{#2}%
      {\@addtoreset{#1}{#2}%
       \expandafter
       \gdef\csname the#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
            {\csname the#2\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
             .\expandafter
           %^^^
             \@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}}}
\makeatother
```