# Building pfdlatex from source with TeX Live

Tags: pdftex, texlive, source

I am trying to build `pdflatex` as part of `TeX Live` from source. Due to a variety of reasons that are not important, I need to build all these tools from scratch.

I have been able to build `TeX Live` from scratch using its source from this github repo: https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source. I loosely followed the build instructions from `TeX Live`'s site here: https://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlbuild.html which for the most part mean running these commands in the checked out repo.

```
# Inside the repo
mkdir OUTPUT
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/OUTPUT --enable-build-in-source-tree
make -j8
make install
```

From which I can see most of the correct binaries like `pdftex` and `latexmk` inside the directory

```
OUTPUT/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

My next goal is to build `pdflatex` (which I learned does not function exactly like `pdftex` as mentioned here: [What's the difference between pdfTeX and pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41031/whats-the-difference-between-pdftex-and-pdflatex)). I am not really sure how to proceed from here though. I believe my next step is to somehow install the `pdflatex` format because it can be passed to the `pdftex` binary as a format flag like

```
pdftex -fmt=pdflatex
```

but I have also seen some other folks saying that `pdflatex` should come installed with `TeX Live`.

Does anyone by chance have experience or knowledge in this area?

Comment: pdflatex is simply a symbolic link to pdftex the texlive tool fmtutil-sys will build the right format

Comment: the texlive-source repo only has the sources for the compiled binaries. To build a format or process documents you need to get all the fonts and tex sources eg from a full texlive repository

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So is the best approach to download a TeXLive repository as outlined here: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html

Comment: that would work (it would also give you ready made binaries but you could discard them and use your own) (which is what I do if I need to test self-compiled binaries)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle on another note, would it be possible and/or easier to simply download the fonts and TeX sources from a TeXLive repo? Rather than downloading the whole repo iteself?

Comment: @nick2225 Well it's SVN so you could just check out the relevant directories

Comment: yes sorry that's what I meant. it's easiest to just do an end user install of texlive, then copy your binaries in to its bin directory for the platform