# Getting and Installing latest development version of Tex Live from source

Tags: installing

What are the steps that allow me to download the sources of the latest development version of Tex Live from source as a `.xz` file.  And how would one build it directly from source?

Comment: Very few people build TeX Live from sources: do you mean simply how do you install the latest release? If so, note that TeX Live 2024 will be released this *week*.

Comment: I mean to build from the current development version.  Everybody should be able to build from source without much headaches.  It is a basic principle to be able to build from source in an efficient way.

Comment: @Ragonese https://tug.org/texlive/build.html

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699334/building-pfdlatex-from-source-with-tex-live might also be relevant, in that if you want to build the binaries yourself, you've still got all of the TeX code to install: easier done by first installing a pre-built TL then replacing the binaries

Comment: Though I will still install TeX Live 2024.  Building from the latest development version is beneficial to test fixes and new features.

Comment: I did go to `https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/` but have not found a way to download as a `tar.gz` file.

Comment: @Ragonese The full TL releases are compressed as `.xz` to make them smaller; personally, I always use an online install

Comment: @Ragonese I'm running TL'24 (pretest): what I don't see is the need to build the binaries oneself :)

Comment: I like to have the sources with which I built the system locally.  It is a standard way to build from source, and so do not understand the rationale for avoiding it.  Building software yourself is a fantastic capability.

Comment: Would you suggest downloading from `https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source` ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151970/discussion-on-question-by-ragonese-getting-and-installing-latest-development-ver); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.