# Error with installing packages

Tags: packages

I'm very new to LaTeX (this is my first time trying to do anything) I keep getting an error that my packages are unable to be read. I was wondering if there was something in the code that was messing this up or if its more of a personal setup issue

**My code for installing packages:**

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}  
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

**The error message:**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./DiscreteHomework7.tex./DiscreteHomework7.tex:2: Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \usepackage
               {geometry}
? 
./DiscreteHomework7.tex:1: Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  [11pt, oneside]{article}
?
```

I would be extremely thankful for any help with this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with installing packages. You are using PDFTeX for a document, that needs PDFLaTeX. Make sure, that you are running `pdflatex DiscreteHomework7` instead of `pdftex DiscreteHomework7`. See also, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41031/277964