# Does TeX/LaTeX give a headstart with other programming languages?

Tags: programming, semantics

I've seen many programmers here at tex.se, and I'd like to know how they view TeX/LaTeX as a programming language in relation to other languages, and whether it would boost my progress as a beginner using other (non-typesetting related) languages, that is of course in an abstract or semantic sense.

Comment: I don't think that learning TeX/LaTeX will help you much with learning other programming languages as TeX/LaTeX has it own very unique _issues_, but knowing other programming languages and basic algorithm development will help you with TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: Well, TeX is really extremly strange programming language, mainly because nowadays "most-used languages" (don't catch me on this word) are mostly concerned of **objects** which are special types of **variables**, whereas TeX is concerned on a **"flow of data and commands"**.

Comment: @PeterGrill Well you see, the first time I tried making a very small program in c++, it took a long while to understand the notion of calling certain libraries. It was latex that made me understand through `\usepackage`.

Comment: @tohecz so would you consider it more like functional programming languages? maybe Lisp?

Comment: I don't want to open a can of worms, maybe you can start digging into *Literate programming*.

Comment: Alas, TeX is not a functional language: although you can have macros that expand to other macros that act like functions, and you can even have macros that define new macros inside them, you can't write, say, `\textit\textbf{A}` to get a bold, italic letter A.

Comment: @RyanReich Ryan has said it well I think. I think it is the exact problem with TeX: you cannot say whether ot is a object language (you can define onjects in some way, but its strange), you cannot say whether it is a functional language (it has some its properties, like said before), you cannot say whether it is a markup language (like HTML, but HTML is not "programmable" whereas TeX is), ...

Comment: I find it a bit weird that people like to confine languages into one or the other programming paradigm, and while there are languages which takes that line of thought to the extremes (eg ruby for "purely" OO, haskell for "purely" functional, etc.), I believe most languages are *multi-paradigm* where you can choose a programming paradigm best suited for the problem at hand. @Ryan: check out `lambda.sty`; it would be interesting IMO to see through the use of that for problems apt for it.

Comment: @morbusg Excellent point! it has been stated numerous times that you can do anything with any language (even with a basic set of functions), it's which one that makes your life easier doing that particular thing (program) that makes the difference.

Comment: @morbusg, Ayman: You are 99% true IMHO, because there are many things you cannot do in **HTML** itself (which is language, at least by its name). But ommiting such few exceptions, I have to agree.

Comment: Could you stop changing the question please!

Comment: @AndrewStacey Sorry, it seemed like a good idea with the first edit but tuned out to be confusing. I apologize.

Comment: @AymanElmasry: You should accept an answer to this question, I think.  I wouldn't mind if you accepted mine, but actually, it seems that I would get a gold badge if you accepted someone else's :)

Comment: @morbusg It's pretty OT but ... I tend to disagree. Practically all languages in actual use are imperative with some elements from other paradigms mixed in that don't, however, change the fact that you can still use imperative thinking for these languages, something that's pretty much useless in Haskell or Prolog. It's not surprising that most languages are imperative of course since that's how computers work after all. Oh and OO and event-driven are just different flavours of imperative programming to me.

Comment: In my humble opinion TeX/LaTeX is not a programming language but a typesetting language which can nicely be abused for some programming-tasks.

Answer (score 154):

My not-oft-enough-expressed opinion is that TeX is a *terrible* programming language and that anyone learning to program is well advised to avoid learning anything from it.  In fact, it is much more helpful to have experience programming in order to write TeX than the opposite.  Various points major and minor come to mind:

- When writing TeX, one has to pay entirely too much attention to the exact characters in the code, up to and including newlines (!) and individual spaces (!!), which both affect its behavior subtly.  This means that lots of effort goes into doing something which isn't even algorithmic.
- Speaking of the input format, because of catcodes, it is entirely fluid.  The example in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38963/575) is extremely interesting, in sort of the same way that [an okapi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi) is interesting.  So even if you think you know TeX's syntax, you (probably) only know the syntax of the plain TeX format.  Or of LaTeX.  Or of ConTeXt.
- TeX is a macro language.  That means that *by design*, its code is *self-modifying*, which is up there with [the `goto` statement](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF) in terms of damage to program structure for the reasons given by Dijkstra in that article.
- However!  TeX is *not* a macro language, because its directives ultimately expand to typesetting primitives.  This fact is prominently advertised in the TeXbook in describing TeX's modes of operation as the "eyes", the "mouth", and the "stomach"; it's the mouth that's the macro language.  The aforementioned issues with input format are the "eyes"; the typesetting part is the "stomach".  Except, of course, when it is *not* just the typesetting, for example the execution of `\def` directives.
- If you read this site, you'll occasionally hear people talking about "fully expandable"; by this they mean code that is processed only in the mouth (as macros).  It is [not really known](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35039/575) why this distinction exists, but as with many aspects of TeX, it may just be an artifact of its age.  This is not a good advertisement for learning a programming language, all other things being equal.
- TeX doesn't actually have programming constructs like variables or loops or conditionals.  It does have registers and the `\loop...\repeat` construct (which works by a clever manipulation of self-modifying code) and it does have a fixed number of builtin `\if`'s, but in general you will find yourself writing an [ad-hoc, informally specified, and bug-ridden implementation of half of Common Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) (or, since I don't actually know Lisp, perhaps I should say "of half of C").  Don't think you'll learn anything this way, other than bad habits.  Unless you already know the structures you're trying to invent you will end up with spaghetti code.
- The constructs that do exist are mostly not expandable, despite the fact that the part of TeX that constitutes a programming language is by definition the purely expandable part.  The fact that *some* of them *are* expandable leads to very obscure tactics, such as the one described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/what-do-firstoftwo-and-secondoftwo-do) and its answers.  It is probably not reasonable to ask programmers to worry about the code branches of an `if` statement actually interfering with the branching code itself.
- TeX has no concept of functions, which is one of the few things that [imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) and functional languages agree on.  Its macros do absorb "arguments", but because of the tricky expansion issues inherent in the macro language, those arguments are not always what is written in the code.  And even if they *are* what's written, because of the tricky [argument-grabbing issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39882/why-does-tex-remove-braces-around-delimited-arguments) they are *still* not always what (you think) is written.
- Strangely, despite the crucial importance of things such as braces to the functioning of TeX, and despite the fact that it *is* a Turing-complete language, and further despite the fact that the exact format of its input is crucial to its functioning, there is no native way to easily do something like determine (expandably, of course) if the next character is a brace!  See Bruno Le Floch's comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40619/575).  This is actually a good lesson on the difference between "Turing-complete" and "can do anything", so in that sense, is a valuable part of one's programming education.
- It has no debugging facilities to speak of.  It does provide the ability to trace code, but this can't be controlled finely and doesn't always reveal crucial facts like "What values do all those variables have right now?".  Assuming you can tell what the variables are, that is, since they are probably macros just like the "functions".

Essentially, programming in TeX is an endless parade of frustration over minutiae concerning code format, multiple rounds of parsing and subsequent (possibly partial) execution, and poorly defined program state.  Although it's true that ["only perl can parse Perl"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Implementation), at least this is true of Perl because of the overwhelming plethora of programming styles and facilities it makes available (including, yes, the ability to modify its own syntax).  In TeX you can have a hard time getting it to do addition.

Comment: Agreed. The day I first implemented an `if` statement that tested more than one Boolean value was the day I realized what a horrible programming language TeX can be. Sometimes TeX is great, sometimes it is a [Turing Tarpit](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit).

Comment: It is a total Turing tarpit. I don't know why brainfuck is supposed to be such a big deal there; TeX did it earlier and far worse.

Comment: There's a slight contradiction: you say that self-modifying code is bad, yet you quote Greenspuns tenth rule. Lisp's macro power often comes from thinking code as data.

Comment: @morbusg: I did say I don't know Lisp :)

Comment: Also: 38 upvotes?  Wow.  So many people on this site hate TeX :)

Comment: Well, as a programming language it’s bloody awful, but as a typesetting system it’s quite alright ;-)

Comment: The question is; do I choose this as a correct answer because so many people seem to agree with it, or choose that which convinces me alone?

Comment: @AymanElmasry: Please, accept the one you prefer.  I've got more than enough points from this answer already.

Comment: @RyanReich Your first criticism also applies to Python, but I actually think that semantic whitespace is one of its strengths.

Comment: @Jubobs Unfortunately, while Python's whitespace enforces coding style, TeX's inhibits it: the more space you add, the worse it gets.  Safe TeX style is to write everything in an unintelligible stream, except of course for the spaces that are necessary to make it parse numbers expandably and correctly.

Comment: After three years...finally, the Great Answer badge for this ironic reponse.  If only the author would accept it finally.

Comment: Phenomenal answer! You wrote: "TeX is *not* a macro language". Are there any true macro programming languages out there?

Comment: Remark: There are ways to [embed an easy programming  language in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77851/250119), and most of the issues are fixed in expl3 (although expl3 is quite verbose).

Comment: Notes: \if\mark\par (true)\fi. \if\a\a\ (perhaps) \else (?)\fi. Comment artificially in order to keep the code safe. You can't simply add two numbers, you change the state of a register. No float numbers.  A macro \def\initspecial{\count0=666} is header of a command, not define by itself the counter value. For reaching such result, you need to \relax at the end. ... Kill my self!  Try to make a macro that gets the first word as argument. Try to load a font you like (no native support to file system). Remember that "1 in" is a very important unit. Too much flexibility to enforce that \n\n=\par.

Answer (score 44):

This is more of a long comment rather than an answer.

TeX is an excellent source of learning programming. **It tells you how *not to* write code!** One of the basic tenets of programming is that you should write code that is easy to read by others. I find that a lot of TeX code, especially TeX macro code written during the early days of TeX, is impossible to read. Part of the reason is the idiosyncrasies of TeX, the macro language. But a bigger reason is the horrible macro naming convention used by macro authors, especially using `@` in the middle of variable names.

As an example, consider the macro `\overset` and `\underset` that are part of the `amsmath` package.  They are defined as

```
 \newcommand{\overset}[2]{\binrel@{#2}%
  \binrel@@{\mathop{\kern\z@#2}\limits^{#1}}}
\newcommand{\underset}[2]{\binrel@{#2}%
  \binrel@@{\mathop{\kern\z@#2}\limits_{#1}}}
```

where the helper macros `\binrel@` and `\binrel@@` are defined in `amsbsy.sty`:

```
\def\binrel@#1{\begingroup
  \setboxz@h{\thinmuskip0mu
    \medmuskip\m@ne mu\thickmuskip\@ne mu
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$#1\m@th$}\kern-\wd\tw@
    ${}#1{}\m@th$}%
  \edef\@tempa{\endgroup\let\noexpand\binrel@@
    \ifdim\wdz@<\z@ \mathbin
    \else\ifdim\wdz@>\z@ \mathrel
    \else \relax\fi\fi}%
  \@tempa
}
\let\binrel@@\relax
```

The above code would have been much easier to read, if the two macros were named `\checkmathbinrel` and `\usemathbinrel` (or something similar). Then, one could read the code to understand the *intent* of the macros.

**Note**: I do not mean to criticize the authors who wrote the code. I understand that the code was written at a time when computational efficiency was more important than readability.

Modern TeX code, whether written in LaTeX3 style or in ConTeXt style is much easier to read. For example, this is how the same macros are defined in ConTeXt:

```
\def\math_binrel_apply#1%
  {\begingroup
   \setbox\scratchbox\hbox
     {\thinmuskip   0mu
      \medmuskip   -1mu
      \thickmuskip -1mu
      \setbox\scratchbox\hbox{$#1\mathsurround\zeropoint$}%
      \kern-\wd\scratchbox
      ${}#1{}\mathsurround\zeropoint$}%
   \ifdim\wd\scratchbox<\zeropoint
     \endgroup
     \expandafter\mathbin
   \else\ifdim\wd\scratchbox>\zeropoint
     \endgroup
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mathrel
   \else
     \endgroup
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\firstofoneargument
   \fi\fi}

\unexpanded\def\overset#1#2%
  {\math_binrel_apply{#2}{\mathop{\kern\zeropoint#2}\limits\normalsuperscript{#1}}}

\unexpanded\def\underset#1#2%
  {\math_binrel_apply{#2}{\mathop{\kern\zeropoint#2}\limits\normalsubscript  {#1}}}
```

Notice that proper indenting and expressive variable names make the code much easier<sup>1</sup> to understand (perhaps at the cost of efficiency).

So, if you read a lot of TeX code, you will come across the same macro written in different styles. You can compare the two implementations to understand how to write readable code.

---

<sup>1</sup>: The `\edef\@tempa{\endgroup ...} \@tempa` trick, or the `{\begingroup ... \engroup \expandafter ... \fi}` trick are standard part of TeX programming.)

Comment: To my eyes, these examples are just degrees of badness. `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter` my behind.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: I am not sure how `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter` is any worse than `\edef\@tempa{\endgroup...}`. In either case, my point is more in term of naming of variables and proper indentation. Even if you were to use the `\edef...{\endgroup...}` form, then, `\@tempa` is just horrible variable name. Something like `\current_math_binrel` would be better.

Comment: Well, in my limited experience, a major part of why the naming is bad is that TeX has limited support for locality. There is no lexical scoping, so you cannot do `{\def\helpermacro{...}\gdef\macro{...\helpermacro...}}`, since `\helpermacro` needs to be in the current scope when `\macro` is expanded. This makes it necessary to make way too many things global, which along with a lack of a namespacing mechanism leads to obscure naming to prevent clashes.

Comment: @Witiko: you can do `\xdef` for expanding `\helpeemacro`

Comment: That I can. But perhaps I do not want to expand `\helpermacro` right away, since there are side effects.

Answer (score 43):

(This is another long comment along the lines of Aditya's answer.)

**Yes**, it *can* help you understand other languages (in a theoretical sense).

And for all the reasons that Ryan gives.

In mathematics, we're always on the look-out for the counterexample, the outlier, the slightly-odd-thing-that-still-satisfies-the-definition.  Indeed, we have whole books whose titles are "Counterexamples in *X*" which are among the "must have" books on people's shelves.  We believe that to truly understand a concept, you have to take it to its extreme and examine what happens there - it's not enough to understand the safe, cosy examples that motivated the concept.  So we learn about the empty set, discrete metric spaces, non-Hausdorff manifolds, non-separable Banach spaces, the field-with-one-element (aka F_un), and many, many similar things.  We do so not because we seriously want to study them, but because if we really want to understand what the statement "S^3 is a smooth manifold" means, we also need to know about the weird examples.

If all you ever want to do is learn one programming language and never be curious as to *why* it works the way it does, then don't bother looking at TeX.  Regard it as Magic and forget about it.  But if you truly want to understand what programming is about, and learn what it can *really* do, then you really should look at TeX because there is nothing quite like it.

Where I'd start is by looking at TeX from the point of view of its purpose (I'm extrapolating back here, I've no real knowledge about its beginnings).  It is a programming language embedded into a document typesetting language, and the latter is the dominant part.  So the programming language has to hide itself most of the time, which is one reason why spaces and new lines are more significant than in other languages: they are significant in the document typesetting part.

The other main unique feature of TeX is that most of its users are not programmers, and would never wish to be.  So, again, its design takes that into account.  A writer would expect `\emph{hello}` to "do what it says on the tin", and `\alpha` to mean "I want an alpha character right here", so expansion - rather than function calls - is closer to what the *average user* expects.

(But I'm no expert, and definitely not a programmer.  So maybe my view is tainted by my programmatic development.)

Comment: Your nickname for TeX—"Counterexamples in Computer Science"—needs to be prominently featured on the site. :-)

Comment: +1!  Though I would say that this is an excellent argument to learn TeX *after* learning another language, so you can reflect on it.  Still, knowing it has been of great value to me in understanding the *execution* of algorithms, if not necessarily their clear and elegant description.

Answer (score 21):

The answers so far have been fairly negative, but let me try to offer a little bit of positive spin on this. I have, in the past, tried to teach a variety of people a little bit of HTML. If they already used LaTeX, then they were already familiar with the idea of a markup language. This made things much easier. Then you can just say "Look, `<i>…</i>` just works like `\textit{…}` does. (I say LaTeX specifically, because that's what people I've talked to use. I don't know if plain TeX or ConTeXt users are any different…)

And then you can use the idea of using `titlesec` or a similar package to modify the title font as a way of introducing the separation of form and content that the divide between HTML and CSS is supposed to effect. (Obviously, in both cases the separation is far from complete, but still…)

So while HTML is also a fairly specific language (arguably not a *programming* language at all) but a familiarity with LaTeX does help in learning it.

What doing this has taught *me* is that most people who use LaTeX use it very badly: `\section*{\it 4. Conclusion}` for example. It seems like LaTeX offers so many different ways of intervening, at different levels, to produce the same or similar output. So you don't get the corrective of seeing your "program" fail often enough that you are forced into the right kind of practices. For example, python forces you to indent properly. (I actually hate semantic whitespace, but it does at least instill a good practice when beginning).

Comment: To reiterate what you've said; since LaTeX is considered more of a mark-up language, people might argue that your statement applies only to HTML. I think even python allows bad practises; like dynamic types for instance.

Comment: @AymanElmasry Yes, if you think of LaTeX as a markup language, then it's OK. But once you realise that TeX does allow for conditionals (and is Turing complete) then it doesn't look good as a general programming language.

Comment: +1 for "most people who use LaTeX use it very badly".  So true.

Answer (score 20):

In 2004 Victor Eijkhout taught a course of Computer Science based on TeX as a programming language.  This year he published the course notes (see http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/the-computer-science-of-tex-and-latex/18798879).  I recently bought this book and I am going to write a review for TUGboat.  My initial impression from this book is that TeX as a language indeed gives you a valuable insight in many aspects of CompSci and programming.

Comment: Interesting. Is your review available on the Internet?

Comment: @Jubobs  http://www.tug.org/books/reviews/tb106reviews-eijkhout.html

Answer (score 17):

This is an interesting question.

I agree with Peter's comment - LaTeX is not a good medium for learning about programming in general, but proficiency in other languages will help you understand LaTeX better. A good language for self-study and experimentation is Python.

The bad news is that working with a concise, flexible, powerful language such as Python will make you realize how incredibly verbose, arcane and crippling programming in TeX and LaTeX actually is. It has been said about Perl that it 'makes simple things simple and hard things possible'. About TeX, it would be fair to say that it makes simple things hard, and hard things virtually impossible.

The good news is that there now is LuaTeX, which allows you to implement all the heavy-lifting inside your own macros in Lua, which is similar to Python in spirit and also in syntax. LuaTeX means that, if you decide to study Lua, you will be rewarded with very real and immediate benefits for your work in TeX and LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to acquire good programming practices, TeX may not be the best choice, as others have mentioned (the `expl3` package aims to correct this, but I don't have personal experience with it). However, if used judiciously, TeX can be a good programming language for learning the foundations of computer science.

The mathematical study of computer programs is couched in the language of [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). TeX lends itself naturally to implementing [Combinatory Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic), which is an equivalent formulation of Lambda Calculus. Combinatory Logic's primitives are the operators

- **I**, the identify operator, which operates on the next token, transforming it to itself. **I**'s defining formula is `(I x) = x`. In TeX

  ```
  \def\I#1{#1}
  ```
- **K**, the constant-function generator, which operates on the next token, `x`, transforming it to an operator that always returns `x`. **K**'s defining formula is `(K x y) = x`. In TeX,

  ```
  \def\K#1#2{#1}
  ```
- **S**, the application operator, whose defining formula is `(S x y z) = (x z (y z))`. In TeX,

  ```
  \def\S#1#2#3{#1#2{#2#3}}
  ```

As such, TeX's closest relatives in the world of computer languages are the family of functional languages, such as Lisp and Haskell, since they are modeled after Lambda Calculus.

However, even in this capacity, TeX is not without its quirks, for instance an empty line will automatically insert a `\par` token into the input stream (but you can avoid this particular problem by starting your scripts with `\endlinechar=-1\relax`).

---

By the way, chapter 5 of the book mentioned in [Boris's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42735/21685) is an introduction to doing Lambda Calculus in TeX.

Comment: Though this may sound fine in theory, in practice TeX's expansion *cannot* “be seen as a general-purpose string rewriting system” for some of the reasons mentioned in Ryan's answer: sensitivity to spaces, and mostly (IMO) the fact that TeX considers expansion as some sort of distraction from its main work of typesetting, to which it will revert at the earliest opportunity. Even if you were an expert at programming in a string-rewriting system or combinatory logic, when you encountered TeX you would still be taken aback. Mostly I'd say: its creator did not intend it for much programming.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Full fledged TeX has many quirks, but you can, if you want to, restrict yourself to using only those aspects of the language that you find desirable. Specifically, if you wish to use it as a combinatory-logic engine, you can restrict yourself to only using `\def`, control-sequences, `\csname...\endcsname`, `{` and `}`. If you do so, there are no quirks, and whitespace can be used liberally. You can then amp it up, if you wish, by judiciously adding to your vocabulary some programming-related primitives, say, `\expandafter`, `\noexpand`, `\ifcase`, `\futurelet`, token registers.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: In hind sight, maybe `\noexpand` is not such a great idea to add to your vocabulary, and if you use `\csname ...\endcsname` you have to include also `\expandafter` in your basic vocabulary, but you can give up `\csname ... \endcsname` if you're willing to settle for control-sequence words (i.e. those control-sequences, whose name consists only of the letters of the alphabet).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Actually, whitespace cannot be used liberally even if you only use control sequences, since an empty line will automatically insert the token `\par`. So yeah, it's not an ideal language...

Comment: @EvanAad See `expl3` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Latex, in my opinion, could be used as a very rich primer for understanding declarative programming. You layout the structure and content of a document declartively and have it rendered to eps or pdf. Even though the language has differences to mobile application frameworks such as as the Android/IOS sdk or web application development using html, css and javascript it presents the coder with the same paradigm of thought used within these contexts.

An appreciation for programming design principles, such as Separation Of Concerns which encourages modular reuse of code blocks is also an advantage of LaTex programming when separating books into chapters, chapters into sections etc.

In short there are many advantages of using this language but again context important. Programming a document layout is not the same as building an application, there are similar concepts employed in both.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.